# No idea how being on service class to get float from seekbar on layoutt. Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-seekbar

My aim is to  manage volume by seekbar of background music.
I created background music by service.
I have media player in Service class:

```
public class ModernService extends Service  {

private MediaPlayer modernsong;
private SeekBar volumeSeekBar;
AudioManager am;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public ModernService() {
    super();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    modernsong =MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.modern);
    modernsong.setLooping(true);
    modernsong.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    modernsong.stop();
}
```

}

The question is how can i get float from a seekbar that is on layout. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First initialize the `volumeSeekbar` and set the max value.

   volumeSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBarId);
   volumeSeekBar.setMax(100);
2. Then you need to add `OnSeekBarChangeListener` to the veiw.

   volumeSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

   ```
           @Override
           public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                   boolean fromUser) {
             //any ui changes you wanted to do on user action on seekbar
           }
       });
   ```
3. Now you can get the value from the seekbar as `volumeSeekBar.getProgress();`
4. In service class `onStartCommand` is having direct access to intent.
   So while starting the service through intent you can pass the seekbar value.

   `Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
       Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
       extras.putString(key, seekbarValue);`

Comment: Can not resolve method  findViewById(). Please say where should i write it in my class without mistake. I understand how to do it in a common class. But not service. Should i create a void method? Sorry, i have only started my Android activity

Comment: You can't get the reference of view in service.  Through the intent you can pass the value to service. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes. Thank you !